# Pine-script for loop inside function

Tags: function, for-loop, pine-script

I'm trying to create a loop to go over the last bars and figure out what the average gain is when the hma is sloping up. But I'm getting an error I don't understand. Is it not possible to have a loop inside a function?

My code:

```
// Get Average Gains on long streaks
getAverageGain(hmaValue) =>
    gainStart = 0.00
    gainAmount = 0.00
    gainCount = 0
    gaining = hmaValue[1] < hmaValue
    for i=0 to 2000
        if gaining[i] and not gaining[i+1]
            gainStart := hmaValue[i]
        if gaining[i+1] and not gaining[i] and gainStart != 0.00
            gainAmount += ((hmaValue[i+1] - gainStart) / gainStart) * 100
            gainCount ++
    gainAmount/gainCount
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `++` operator in pinescript. Change it to `gainCount := gainCount + 1`.

You can see the list of operators in pinescript from [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html).

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with the double + sign....not the for loop

gainCount ++

Unfortunately Pine-script's error messages aren't always clear enough